# Monetary and fiscal policies: problem and solution approach

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, monetary-policy, soft-question, fiscal-policy

Can the community recommend resources about macroeconomics / public finance that (roughly) follow the following design:

- Here's a macroeconomics / public finance economic problem (description, potential cause(s), real-life example(s))
- Here's solution 1 according to X theory or X' school of economics
- Here's solution 2 according to Y theory or Y' school of economics, etc.

That is, the resources will follow a basic problem-solution approach.

p.s. My background: years ago I took graduate level macroeconomics. I have since forgotten a lot of the theories, but I still retain the mathematical skills and maturity to pick the theories back up, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some good resources:

- Richard Tresch (2014) public finance: a normative theory
- Dennis Mueller Public Choice III
- Jean Hindriks and Gareth D. Myles (2013)Intermediate Public Economics

The last one is probably most close to what you want.

However, this being said I know of no source that would give overview of theories of all schools of thought on a topic.

Most graduate level textbooks will focus on the theories that are considered to be more or less plausible rather than examining and contrasting ideas from every school of thought. Also nowadays separating economics in that way does not make as much sense as it did a century or half-century ago. Nowadays any idea that is considered to be successful especially empirically so will quickly get integrated into mainstream.